# How do I get the computational time of my code using this Python code?

Tags: python, time

I found the following code on a different question. But, I'm not sure where to place my code. I've tried placing my code after the entire code, and then tried placing it between the start=time() line and the ones after it. But, none of these are printing an elapsed time. Anyone know where I would place my lines of code to get an elapsed time printed?

```
#python3
import atexit
from time import time, strftime, localtime
from datetime import timedelta

def secondsToStr(elapsed=None):
    if elapsed is None:
        return strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime())
    else:
        return str(timedelta(seconds=elapsed))

def log(s, elapsed=None):
    line = "="*40
    print(line)
    print(secondsToStr(), '-', s)
    if elapsed:
        print("Elapsed time:", elapsed)
    print(line)
    print()

def endlog():
    end = time()
    elapsed = end-start
    log("End Program", secondsToStr(elapsed))

start = time()
atexit.register(endlog)
log("Start Program")
```

Update: I ended up using this code instead:

```
import pandas as pd
start = pd.Timestamp.now()
# code
print(pd.Timestamp.now()-start)
```

Comment: What is it that you're trying to time, exactly?

Comment: The time it takes to run my code. I'm trying to compare the time it takes to run a cGAN model vs. topology optimization code to generate 100 figures.

Comment: One good way is to use builtin magic function %timeit , if you have jupyter notebook have a look : https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html

Answer (score 0):

That's more elaborate than it needs to be.  As long as you can identify the exact code you want to time, it's just:

```
import time
...
start = time.time()
execute_my_code_1()
elapsed1 = time.time() - start

start = time.time()
execute_my_code_2()
elapsed2 = time.time() - start

print(f"One took {elapsed1}s, two took {elapsed2}s.")
```

Comment: I ended up using the code in my edit. Is that accurate, do you think? And thanks Tim!

Comment: Yes.  I don't know why you would use pandas's timestamp instead of the one built-in to Python, but that doesn't matter.